# unfortunately <app><package> has stopped in android emulator-error ,How to solve this?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-emulator

I am new to android app development( from yesterday only i started to learn android ).

I am getting message in AVD like - unfortunately  has stopped ,please help me solve this error, I want learn more in android but sucked by this error.. plz..plz.. help me to sove this.

my MainActivity is

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton mb=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageButton mc=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    ImageButton me=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    ImageButton mf=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    ImageButton mg=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    ImageButton mh=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);

    mb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent activityChangeIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);               
MainActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

        }
    });
    mc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class ));

        }
    });


           me.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class ));

    }
});



         mf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class ));

    }
});
   mg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class ));

    }
});


          mh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class ));

    }
});


}

}
```

My MainActivity XML is :

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/bg1"

           >
        <TableLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:stretchColumns="*" >

         <TableRow> 


    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/mob1" />

    <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
   android:padding="20dp"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:background="@drawable/cam1" />

  </TableRow>
  <TableRow >


   <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/comp" />

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/watch1" />

  </TableRow>
 <TableRow >



   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/abt1" />

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/contact1" />

   </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

MY Logcat is :

```
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.somayaji.abhi/com.somayaji.abhi.Second}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at com.somayaji.abhi.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-04 05:14:36.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 05:14:49.691: I/Process(1088): Sending signal. PID: 1088 SIG: 9
```

my Second activity is

```
  public class Second extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mpage); 
    }
   }
```

My second activity XML is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/TextView" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

plz.. explain why am getting like this.. tell me the solution

Comment: hello pls add your manifest too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Straight from logcat :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.somayaji.abhi/com.somayaji.abhi.Second}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You have forgotten to declare your `Second` activity in your manifest xml file.

Try to read the logcat, messages are often very informative and you'll be able to correct your error faster than post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the Second activity

```
 <activity android:name="com.somayaji.abhi.Second" >
 </activity>
```

in manifest file

Check the topic Add it to manifest

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an ActivityNotFound Exception.

include

```
 <activity android:name="com.somayaji.abhi.Second" >
 </activity>
```

inside Application tag of your Manifest file.